Extract partial data from json list of objects in SQLite
Say we have database table like this:
CREATE TABLE tbl 
(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,  
    data JSON
); 

and JSON data like this:
INSERT INTO tbl (data) 
VALUES ('[
             {
                "name": "object 1",
                "key": "value 1",
                "unwanted key": "unwanted value 1"
             },
             {
                "name": "object 2",
                "key": "value 2",
                "unwanted key": "unwanted value 2"
             }
         ]');

Now I'd like to extract only part of the data, while keeping it as a list of objects, where every object just has the name and the and the key key, but not the unwanted key. Moreover if I have multiple rows with the same structured list in the data column, I need to be able to differentiate (by id for example), when selecting all data.
I have tried to do this with a combination of json_each and json_extract like in this example, but that gives me a result for each object in a list, not for each list and I could not figure out how to change that.
It would also be possible to just split the table and create a new column just for the unwanted key, but that would leave me to put it all together a another point in the application. But if the query is impossible with this structure I would fall back to changing the schema.
Edit to add expected results: let's say we insert the same list twice I'd like to get this output:



id
data




1
[{"name": "object 1", "key": "value 1"}, {"name": "object 2", "key": "value 2"}]


2
[{"name": "object 1", "key": "value 1"}, {"name": "object 2", "key": "value 2"}]




...just normalize your data first. Storing JSON directly in an RDBMS is just so wrong.

@Dai could you please explain? I'm new to this field, I don't know what normalize means in this context. I stored it in JSON, because I won't be able to store lists of arbitrary length otherwise.

I'm saying you should design your database following the straightforward rules for normalization: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization - to "store a list of arbitrary length" you'd store those list elements in another table with an FK to their parent row, for example. (Have you taken any courses on database-theory?)

@Dai so I have an N-to-M relation table? Would't that just use more space that "only" splitting the JSON? And use more computing time as I have to manually parse the data before storing? (No I have not, I just googled stuff together and learned from the sqlite documentation)

It's actually much faster.

@JuA Can you edit the question and add the exact output you're expecting?

@Dogbert I have done so, thanks for the reminder

You can extract the selected columns using a combination of json_each, json_object and json_group_array like this:
select
  id,
  (select json_group_array(
    json_object('name', value->'$.name', 'key', value->'$.key')
   )
   from json_each(data)) as data
from tbl;

Input:
CREATE TABLE tbl (id INT PRIMARY KEY, data JSON);

INSERT INTO tbl (id, data) VALUES (1, '[
        {
                "name": "object 1",
                "key": "value 1",
                "unwanted key": "unwanted value 1"
        },
        {
                "name": "object 2",
                "key": "value 2",
                "unwanted key": "unwanted value 2"
        }
]'), (2, '[
        {
                "name": "object 3",
                "key": "value 3",
                "unwanted key": "unwanted value 3"
        }
]');

Output:
1|[{"name":"object 1","key":"value 1"},{"name":"object 2","key":"value 2"}]
2|[{"name":"object 3","key":"value 3"}]


Thanks for the quick answer. Unfortunately, I got an Error: in prepare, near ">": syntax error (1). I do think I understand your answer in theory, but I don't know how to debug that. I also created a new table with the commands you provided.

What version of SQLite are you on? (Run select sqlite_version() to find out.)

it's version 3.37.2, I guess that's what in the ubuntu repositories at the moment.

I could just test it on a different device with SQLite version 3.42.0 and your answer works there. That's good enough for me at the moment, but I'd be interested in the differences between these versions. And if you'd know how to adapt that to older versions of SQLite it would be for the interest, too. Thanks a lot!

-> operator was added in 3.38.0. Can you see if json_extract works: change value->'$.name' to json_extract(value, '$.name') and the same for the other one.

yes that works in both versions! Thank you very much for your help!
